# Move All Columns Of A Matrix To The Left By One C++

Tags: c++, matrix, c++17

my problem is to take a matrix ***mat*** of ***rowcol*** length, and move each column within it one position to the left.
For example if i have a 3x3 matrix like this:

```
4 5 2
6 7 3 
3 4 6
```

the result should must be like this:

```
5 2 4
7 3 6
4 6 3
```

I can't get the method to work, how many times I do it, does anyone have any ideas?

Below my code:

```
for(int i = rowcol - 1; i > 0; i--)
            for(int j = 0; j < rowcol; j++) {
                if(i == 0) swap(mat[j][rowcol - 1], mat[j][i]);
                swap(mat[j][i], mat[j][i-1]);
            }
```

Comment: With `i > 0` as a loop condition, `i == 0` will never be `true`.  You probably intended for the condition to be `i >= 0`.

Comment: I’m not sure that calling swap() is the easiest way to implement this.  Perhaps instead just save the leftmost value into a local variable, then overwrite each value with the value in the next column (except for the last column; for that you’d use your saved local variable instead)

Comment: depending on the structure of data in the matrix, `std::rotate` would be easy. For instance `std::array<std::array<int, NCols>, Nrows>` rotate would do the job

Comment: salex Your method actually works! can you send the complete code to explain why you say it doesn't??

Answer (score 3):

The standard library has an algorithm to do what you're asking: [`std::rotate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate). The following example rotates everything *right* one column.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    int arr[][3] = {
        { 1,2,3 },
        { 4,5,6 },
        { 7,8,9 }
    };

    for (auto& row : arr)
    {
        std::rotate(row, row+2, row+3);
    }

    for (auto& row : arr)
    {
        for (auto x : row)
            std::cout << x << ' ';
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
3 1 2 
6 4 5 
9 7 8
```

Obviously the conditions of your matrix access to individual rows can be (and is likely) different than the above trivial example, but nonetheless, the concept is still the same. I leave it to you to play with for learning how to do it "left" (it won't be hard <sup>*</sup>).

<sub>hint: `std::rotate(row, row+1, row+3);`</sub>

Answer (score 1):

**Here's my updated solution.** It's even easier than the original one I posted a few minutes earlier.

Basically, for each row:

- Save off the value in the first column
- Shift all the values (starting at column 1) in the row by one to the left.
- The last value in the row is the previously saved variable from the first step

Code:

```
for (size_t row = 0; row < rowcol; row++) {
   int tmp = mat[row][0];
   for (size_t col = 1; col < rowcol; col++) {
       mat[row][col-1] = mat[row][col];
   }
   mat[row][rowcol-1] = tmp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about as follows ?

```
  for ( auto ui = 0u ; ui < rowcol ; ++ui )
    for ( auto uj = 1u ; uj < rowcol ; ++uj )
      std::swap(mat[ui][uj-1], mat[ui][uj]);
```

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <iostream>
    
static constexpr std::size_t  rowcol = 3u;

void printMat (int mat[rowcol][rowcol])
{
  for ( auto ui = 0u ; ui < rowcol ; ++ui ) {
    for ( auto uj = 0u ; uj < rowcol ; ++uj )
      std::cout << mat[ui][uj] << ' ';

    std::cout << std::endl;
  }

  std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  int mat[rowcol][rowcol] { {4, 5, 2}, {6, 7, 3}, {3, 4, 6} };

  printMat(mat);

  for ( auto ui = 0u ; ui < rowcol ; ++ui )
    for ( auto uj = 1u ; uj < rowcol ; ++uj )
      std::swap(mat[ui][uj-1], mat[ui][uj]);

  printMat(mat);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is correct except, you're actually shifting the columns of the matrix one position to the right, not left. Not only that, the (i==0) condition is not required.

Replace the backward iteration with forward iteration and get rid of the conditional statement and you're good to go. Here's the modified code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < rowcol-1; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < rowcol; j++) {
            // if(i == 0) swap(mat[j][rowcol - 1], mat[j][i]);
            swap(mat[j][i], mat[j][i+1]);
        }
```

Basically your logic is similar to [Bubble Sort](https://www.programiz.com/dsa/bubble-sort). You were bubbling the final column towards the beginning of the matrix by shifting all other columns rightward.

I inverted it by making it so that we are bubbling the first column towards the end instead. Feel free to ask any questions.